# Bind Interface in WPF for ComboBox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, interface, entity-framework-core

I've read all over the place, that binding is doable in WPF to Interfaces, but I'm having a heck of a time actually getting any traction with it. I'm using EF Core also, if it helps you ready my code. The ComboBox fills with data, so the bind of the data works, but `SelectedItem` fails to bind, and the text within the selected item shows blank.

I don't get how the following, binds to the object that implements the interface.

The XAML for ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" x:Name="cbJumpList" Width="177" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            IsEditable="False"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=(model:IData.SelectedJumpList), Mode=TwoWay}"
            />
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
protected IData DB { get; private set; }
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DB = new Data.DataSQLite(true);
    DB.Bind_JumpLists_ItemsSource(cbJumpList);
}
```

IData.cs:

```
public interface IData : IDisposable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    void Bind_JumpLists_ItemsSource(ItemsControl control);
    IJumpList First_JumpList();

    IJumpList SelectedJumpList { get; set; } // TwoWay Binding
}
```

IJumpList.cs

```
public interface IJumpList
{
    long JumpListId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then within the implemented object (Data.DataSQLite):

```
public void Bind_JumpLists_ItemsSource(ItemsControl control)
{
    control.ItemsSource = null;

    db.JumpLists.ToList();
    control.ItemsSource = db.JumpLists.Local;
    control.Tag = db.JumpLists.Local;

    SelectedJumpList = db.JumpLists.FirstOrDefault();
}

public IJumpList SelectedJumpList
{
    get { return _SelectedJumpList; }
    set
    {
        _SelectedJumpList = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
IJumpList _SelectedJumpList;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

I should add, the PropertyChanged event remains null.

Comment: Trying to bind list returned from `ToList()` to SelectedItem property? Also what is inside `IJumpList`?

Comment: @SivaGopal No, the ToList is updating the `Items.Local` property used in another binding elsewhere. I figured that might cause confusion, I'll edit it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SelectedItem` property of a `ComboBox` is supposed to be bound to a property and not to a type. For the binding to work you should also set the `DataContext` of the `ComboBox` to an instance of the type where this property is defined.

Try this:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" x:Name="cbJumpList" Width="177" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          IsEditable="False"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedJumpList}" />
```

---

```
public void Bind_JumpLists_ItemsSource(ItemsControl control)
{
    db.JumpLists.ToList();
    control.DataContext = this;
    control.ItemsSource = db.JumpLists.Local;
    control.Tag = db.JumpLists.Local;

    SelectedJumpList = db.JumpLists.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: mm8 Thank you. The `control.DataContext = this;` on the instance of the type was the key. Changing SelectedItem didn't matter. Your way worked, and so did what I have. Now I have to work at getting it to update my other list that changing it affects, but this is a big bump. Can't believe someone downvoted it, since it is the solution.